# Assigning a character to the Caps Lock key in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I'm using a German keyboard in Ubuntu. As we need the slash on the console quite often and it is somewhat awkward to type on a German keyboard, I'd like to assign the <kbd>/</kbd> key to the unused <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Here are the exact commands:

```
cd ~
xmodmap -e "keycode 66 = slash"
`xmodmap -pke > .Xmodmap`
echo "xmodmap .Xmodmap" >> .xinitrc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always do it with '*xmodmap*'.

Hope these links are useful,

https://askubuntu.com/questions/24916/how-do-i-remap-certain-keys

http://www.linuxscrew.com/2008/09/15/faq-how-to-disableremap-a-keyboard-key-in-linux/

FYI,

Caps Lock: keycode 66

Slash    : keycode 61

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.